# flex VideoDisplay child always to be the same size as the VideoDisplay

Tags: apache-flex, layout, video-streaming

i have a VideoDisplay

```
 <mx:VideoDisplay id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%">      
</mx:VideoDisplay>
```

and i put the video like this:

```
video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream(ns);
myVideo.addChild(video);
```

and i want to make the child inside VideoDisplay to resize with him to make his size 100%/100% (size of the child)

cuz video.height and width accept only integers and ican't put % in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:D i found the answer myself
all i had to do is this:

```
<mx:VideoDisplay id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" resize="video.height=myVideo.height; video.width=myVideo.width;">      
</mx:VideoDisplay>
```